# Circular imports in python (again)

Tags: python, python-import, circular-dependency

I have two classes in two python files, and I'd like to be able to convert objects of one class to another:

```
# In a.py
from b import B
class A:
    def convertToB(self):
        return B(...)

# In b.py
from a import A
class B:
    def convertToA(self):
        return A(...)
```

Obviously, I get a circular import error. **How can I solve this?** I don't want to:

- Use absolute imports - because names deep within the hierarchy get too long
- Defer imports - because it feels hacky/messy
- Use a central imports module - because names get super long again

I'd prefer not changing the design, as I think it is conceptually fine.